# Handling event inside loaded swf in MATE

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, flex3, mate

Can I handle an event inside a loaded swf file(using swf loader) using MATE when my main application fires the event ? i want to make a remote service call based on the data i get from the main applications event , and then populate my loaded swf .

Answer (score 0):

It really depends how things are loaded.  By default, no, Mate cannot do this because of the way events work; they go *up* the display list, and not down to the children.

The only way I can think of doing this is to wait for the swf to finish loading and then listen for the even on the root application (in Flex do `FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.addEventListener`).  However, this is a huge hack and shouldn't be done.  The real problem here is how your application is architected, and you should look into how to solve the issue at its core.

Comment: I feel the reason for MATE not able to do this is different that the one you specified.